# Creating Map Tips with ArcGIS API for Flex

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, maptips

I'd like to have Map Tips display when a user hovers over, or clicks on, a feature in my Flex Application.

Would I do this in the authoring stage or is there code I write into my Flex application?

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "map tip" on [Esri's Flex API site](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/index.html) yielded these results:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=MapTips

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=InfoWindowRollOverSample

Comment: Both links are broken and lead to same message: "On June 1, 2016 the ArcGIS API for Flex entered the retired phase of its product life cycle. There will be no further updates to the product or its documentation."